# Sum value of col 3 based on col 1 and col 2 value

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, vlookup, google-query-language

I want to sum value of col3 based on col1 and col2

here is the link of dummy data sheet in which I have shown sample table according to which I want sum of col 3  please guys check the sheet and suggest me some solution for it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_MeiySJHI8OD84BPDOj_z57My-TXbs2ey4AOkQP3zug/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Possibly - SUMIFS() - Can you provide an example? Either create another sample sheet with any private info removed or a screenshot of what you are working with.

Comment: Excel is not Google Sheets. Please ensure you use appropriate tags to receive an appropriate solution.

Comment: @KrispinMiller Thanks for your suggestion bro i have used SUMIFS() but it is not helping so as you have asked for sample sheet i have created and shared it along with question please check and give me your suggestion and thanks for your time.

Comment: @BigBen but logic which we are using in excel and google sheet is same, right so that's why I used excel tag so that people who know excel they can help me with this.

Comment: That's not correct. For example, the posted answer uses `QUERY`, which exists only in Sheets. Using the appropriate tags would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY(A:C; "select A,B,sum(C) where A is not null group by A,B label sum(C)''")
```

---

### update:

```
={"result"; INDEX(IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A&" "&B2:B, A2:A&" "&B2:B, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&" "&B2:B, 
 QUERY({A2:A&" "&B2:B, C2:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), 2, 0)), ))}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @player0 for your help, but I want to sum third column based on two column. I have shared the link of google sheet on which I have created dummy data set along with in which way I want sum I have explained in that sheet.

Comment: @new1 answer updated

Comment: thank you so much for your help sir can you please suggest me some sites or blogs using which I can learn the logic like this for excel or google sheets and is their any other medium through which I can interact with you